# Definition of algebraic function

Tags: reference-request, definition, algebraic-number-theory

I am unable to find a reference where the definition of algebraic functions is given. I am looking for one.

For example, I see in many lectures that the function $\left\{\begin{array}{crcl}f:&\mathopen[0,+\infty\mathclose[&\to&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\sqrt{x}\end{array}\right.$ is an algebraic function. But for me, algebraic means "over a field" and since the algebra of functions $\left\{g:\mathopen[0,+\infty\mathclose[ \to\mathbb R\right\}$ is not integral, it can not be endowed in a field. So talking about algebraic function is misleading for me.

That's why I am looking for a precise definition of algebraic function.

Comment: The terminology refers to functions that are algebraic over the embedded constant field of rational functions.  For example, $f$ is algebraic because it satisfies $f(x)^2 - x = 0$.

Comment: ([Typo](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1175938): "the field of rational functions"; "embedded constant" does not belong.)  [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1175939), once you consider functions with domains on, say, different intervals, you start losing nice algebraic properties (what is the domain of $\sqrt{x - 1} + \sqrt{-2 - x}$?), so it may not be so useful to think of the resulting structure as a field.  Your TeX does not seem to render as intended, but, no, we do not require that rational functions be everywhere defined.

Comment: So i do not still understand. Is the function $\left\{\begin{array}{crcl}f:&\mathbb R&\to\´\mathbb R\\&x\mapsto&\begin{cases}e^x&\text{if }x<0\\\sqrt x&\text{if }x\ge 0\}\end{array}\right.$ algebraic?. With your definition one can find a smaill set where it is, but globally it is not.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454334/definition-of-algebraic-function#comment1175943_454334), I agree.  I am only used to seeing the term in calculus textbooks, where algebraic subtleties tend to be less regarded.  If I were to see the term in a more advanced mathematical context, then I would expect to see more details—and, of course, any proofs would give a hint of what was meant.  Where are you seeing the term?

Comment: FWIW, one can easily give a precise definition for what it means for a formal power series to be algebraic, so that $(1+x)^{1/2}$ is algebraic (though not $x^{1/2}$, which doesn’t make sense as a formal power series).

Comment: Read [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Algebraic_function). Is this discussion sufficiently rigorous? The trick is to think not of a function of one variable but of a rational function of several variables restricted to a suitable affine algebraic curve. Ditto for algebraic functions of several variables.

Comment: Relevant: The MSE question [Precise definition of an "algebraic function"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2813115/13130). Among other things of possible interest there, see the paper I cite in a comment to GEdgar's answer. (**Site operation note:** I remembered writing something to this effect in a comment, looked through my recent comments in mathoverflow and found it, but when I click on the question itself my comment no longer appears. However, I was able to copy the comment from my list of recent comments. If my comment was deleted for some reason, **(continued)**

Comment: then please note that the MSE question I cited is nearly (if not actually) a duplicate and both GEdgar's answer there and my comment there are particularly relevant to the present question. The reason I gave this in a comment is because link-only answers are strongly discouraged and I don't have the time or interest now (or 6 days ago when I wrote my apparently deleted comment) to properly write an answer. Incidentally, my happening to remember that over 5 years old MSE question and locating it was a nontrivial task, and having that work erased by a comment deletion is a bit irritating.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, [re](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/commens/10136281), is the comment you mean [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/5801326)? It still shows up for me. I copy the reference from there: "Fred Richman, *[Algebraic functions, calculus style](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2011.584337)*, Communications in Algebra 40 #7 (2012), pp. 2671-2683 ([27 July 2010 preprint version](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.304.6160&rep=rep1&type=pdf))."

Comment: @LSpice: No, I did not mean the comment to GEdgar's answer from over 5 years ago, but instead comments to THIS question that were made before this question migrated from mathoverflow to MSE (note I said "...  6 days ago when I wrote my apparently deleted comment"). Regarding your [re](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/commens/10136281) link, the URL sent me to a page saying (in part) "Page not found
We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested." Incidentally, if this message arises due to my not having an appropriate reputation **(continued)**

Comment: or some appropriate administration privilege, then the message should probably say this. There is a big difference between not being able to find a certain page (e.g. a dead link, URL incorrectly typed at very end somewhere, etc.) and failing to have the appropriate permission. Of course I realize that probably no one reading this, even a MSE moderator, has any authority for something like this.